# Creating a custom iterator that reads consecutive files

Tags: java, iterator

We have

```
public class UKWacSentenceIterator implements SentenceIterator
```

which is obviously an Tterator but I don't have any information on what's in `SentenceIterator`. This class has this property: `Scanner fileScanner`.

The idea is that the constructor takes an array of files:

```
public UKWacSentenceIterator() throws IOException {
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.load(prop.class.getClassLoader()
           .getResourceAsStream("sources/ukwacdump.properties"));
    Enumeration<Object> keys = p.elements();  
    while (keys.hasMoreElements()) { 
        source.add(keys.nextElement());
    }
    fileScanner = new Scanner(new File((String) source.get(0)));
}
```

And in the main method we can use a for loop:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    for(String line : new UKWacSentenceIterator()) {
        System.out.println(line);   
    }
}
```

He has currently having a problem with this for loop because once the first file is `EOF` the for just stops. So he thought would be a good idea to override

```
@Override
public boolean hasNext() {
    if(tmp != null) {
        return true;
    }
    if (this.fileScanner.hasNext()) {
        try {
            this.skipToSequenceStart();
            String sent = this.scanSentence();
            this.tmp = sent;
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return advanceFileScanner();
    }
}
```

But he doesn't know how to build `advanceFileScanner()`.

My idea is to just to assign the variable `fileScanner` to a new `Scanner` with the next file name and then just copy

```
this.skipToSequenceStart();
String sent = this.scanSentence();
this.tmp = sent;
return true;
```

I don't know if he tried yet. I was wondering if you think is a good idea and if you can suggest me a good tutorial on how to create an iterable object. Because right now I'm just guessing, I don't know what the for loop use other than `hasNext()`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but isn't your problem simply that your

```
fileScanner = new Scanner(new File((String) source.get(0)));
```

only contains 1 file

I explain. I use to read in many file given a string array of all the files I have to read. Me, I do it that way, I simply declare as an []. I give you an exemple of my code.

```
BufferedReader[] reader = new BufferedReader[myArrayFiles.length];
for (int i = 0; i < myArrayFiles.length; i++) {
    reader[i] = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(myArrayFile[i]));
    //do my reading
    reader.close();
}
```

It is with buffered reader but I think you could apply it to your code. Could you do something like that (is source an array ? i assume yes so i use length. Perhaps it's "size()" in your case).

```
Scanner[] fileScanner = new Scanner[source.length()];
for (i = 0; i < source.length(); i++) {
  fileScanner[i] = new Scanner(new File((String) source.get(i)));
}
```

Then of course you have to refactor the rest of the code to handel the filescanner array

Hope it helps

Comment: I don't think that would be so much different. In the case of my friend he's just updating the only file scanner he has. The new filescanner would be inside the advanceFileScanner method, maybe using a counter. What I'm really interested is in understanding from where the for loop gets the information it needs.